# Packet forwarding between nics in same network (wifi/eth)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, wireless-bridge

I need to setup (if possible) a device with to nics, one ethernet and one wireless, were each packet coming from the wireless side is forwarded as is whitout modifcations to the ethernet port and viceversa.

The device is moving over several APs in the same network as the component behind the ethernet nic and I need to be able to send packets (IP based) from the wireless side to the ethernet side and back.

I need to specify that the device behind the ethernet port (a PLC) is silent until it receives a packet, therefore the wireless side needs to accept packets as if it was the device behind the ethernet port.

Normaly I would set up a router or a bridge between the nics, but since they are in the same network neither method seems to fit the bill.

The operating system is Linux (preferable Debian). Is there a configuration that permits this behaviour?

Edit: the device needs only to connect one ethernet device to a wireless network.

Comment: That is litterally a bridge. Google how to bridge wireless and wired in linux.

Comment: I edited the question. If the two sides were wired I think the bridge would do the job if correctly configured. With wireless I have the problem that the AP registers the bridges Mac Address and does not send packets for the client behind the ethernet port, therefore I can start the connection from the ethernet side, but I cannot open a connection (or receive udp packets) from the wireless side.

Comment: You need to put the wifi adapter into promiscuous mode...

Comment: Thanks djsmiley2k. Promiscuous mode brought me a bit further, but the main problem persists: I can't get the Ap to send packets directly to the ethernet side, only packets for the wifi adapter (from ap to wifi mac) are sent. Is it possible to modify the mac address of the wifi nic to the same as the device behind the eth adapter?

Comment: If it's bridging properly, everything should have the (virtual?) mac address of the bridge, not the wifi adaptor or wired adapter. At least this is how I understand it to work.

Comment: That's a FAQ, has been asked in various variants. To bridge a WLAN client and LAN, you need 4-address mode on your WLAN (**all** of it, i.e. all devices must support it). Bridging a WLAN client in 3-address mode doesn't work. Otherwise, if the device itself doesn't need to be on the LAN, there is a software called wlankabel using packet sockets to directly forward packets.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Thats the problem, everything has the Mac of the bridge, but the packets is not part of a connection oriented protocol, but an UDP packet that is addressed to the device behind the ethernet port. To be clear the comunication is as follows: PLC1 - AP - WirelessBridgeNic - EthernetBridgeNic - PLC2 and viceversa. PLC1 sends packets directly to PLC2 not to the WirelessBridgeNic.

Comment: @dirkt Thats the point. For what I understand i would need to route the packets from one Nic to the other not bridging the nics., but with routing I end up with the same problem (and a few other ones) as with the bridging solution: the Mac address of the nic connected to the APs is the one of the wireless card on my device and therefore I cannot send an UDP packet for example directly to the plc behind the ethernet port, because the AP won't send it.

Comment: No, for the 3-address scenario, neither routing nor bridging will work. As I said, it's a FAQ, and their's no easy solution. You can NAT, but that only works for outgoing requests, not for the incoming ones you need, unless you can live with port forwarding the ports you need. I don't have the link for the wlankabel app here, and google isn't helpful; I'll look it up later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick recap of comments:

This is a FAQ, lots of people want to bridge LAN to WLAN, but unfortunately it's not easy.

Unless you enable 4-address mode on all devices in the WLAN, it's not possible to bridge a WLAN **client** to LAN (it works for a WLAN access point). Routing also doesn't work, unless it's between different network segments on WLAN and LAN, and then the WLAN AP has to be configured for that.

One alternative is [wlan_kabel](https://github.com/escitalopram/wlan_kabel), which proxies a single device on LAN to WLAN using packet sockets to intercept the packets. In this process, the intermediate device becomes invisible on the WLAN.